# Error in my recursive Vue component, how do I find it?

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js, vue-component

I'm building a questionnaire and the source js file of the questions is about 4500 lines. I'm getting a type error on something and I can't find the line that is causing it. Here is the error.

[image: This is the error here.]

My component looks like

```html
<template>
  <div class="form-panel">
    <h3 class="section__sub-header">{{ title }}</h3>
    <InputCheckbox @change="toggleChild" v-if="options" :inputParams="[safe, options, false]"></InputCheckbox>
    <InputPanel v-for="(node, i) in nodes" :key="i"
      v-show="checked.indexOf(options[i][0]) !== -1"
      @update="emitChecked"
      :title="node.title"
      :options="node.options"
      :nodes="node.nodes"
      :safe="options[i][0]"></InputPanel>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the source data is structured like:

```js
productsServicesOptions: {
    title: 'Products and Services',
    options: [
      ['automotive', 'Automotive'],
      ['commercialIndustrialServices', 'Commercial & Industrial Services'],
      ['contractorsConstructions', 'Contractors & Constructions'],
      ['foodServices', 'Food Services'],
      ['healthBeautyWellBeing', 'Health, Beauty & Well-Being'],
      ['homeMaintenance', 'Home & Maintenance'],
      ['lawFinance', 'Law & Finance'],
      ['miscellaneous', 'Miscellaneous']
    ],
    nodes: [{
        title: 'Automotive',
        options: [
          ['glassAutomobile', 'Glass – Automobiles'],
          ['autoBodyRepairingPainting', 'Auto Body Repairing & Painting'],
          ['automobilePartsSupplies', 'Automobile Parts & Supplies'],
          ['automobileRepairingService', 'Automobile Repairing & Service'],
          ['autoWreckingRecycling', 'Auto Wrecking & Recycling'],
          ['homeMaintenance', 'Garages Auto Repairing'],
          ['tireDealersRetail', 'Tire Dealers – Retail'],
          ['towingAutomotive', 'Towing – Automotive'],
          ['transmissionsAutomotive', 'Transmissions – Automotive'],
          ['truckRepairingService', 'Truck Repairing & Service']
        ],
        nodes: [{ ...etc
```

I have determined that the error comes from calling options[0] which makes me think some of the source data isn't formatted in an array properly. I had to write a script to convert a 70 page word doc into this structure so it's definitely plausible my data is bad. How can I find the error in the source file to the line?

Comment: Maybe put in [prop validation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few of the node objects got shuffled around was throwing off the array lengths. It helped a ton to swap v-show to v-if so I could check one question at a time, even if it was tedious